# Getting SSL exception in eclipse

Tags: java, spring-boot, web-services

I am getting ssl exception while accessing a soap webservice. Same API is accessible through SOAP UI tool.
I have checked proxy setting and I don not  see any issue with it. also verified certificates and they are not yet expired

```
URL u = new URL(apiURL);
            //  URLConnection uc = u.openConnection();
                HttpsURLConnection uc = (HttpsURLConnection) u.openConnection();
                connection = (HttpsURLConnection) uc;
                connection.setDoOutput(true);
                connection.setDoInput(true);
                connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=UTF-8");
            //  connection.setRequestProperty("SOAPAction", apiURL);
            //  connection.connect();
                OutputStream out = connection.getOutputStream();
                Writer wout = new OutputStreamWriter(out);
                wout.write(request);
                wout.flush();
                wout.close();
                out.close();






javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.handleUnknownRecord(InputRecord.java:710)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:527)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:983)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1385)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1413)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1397)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559)
    

at 
 sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.
connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
  at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1334)
            at 
sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1309)
            at 
sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:

259)
```

Comment: Are you certain the connection you are trying to establish is available via ssl?

Comment: hi Jakob, yes as same endpoint is working fine in soap ui tool and postman

Answer (score 0):

The error says that you got a plain text messsage instead of a crypted ssl message, this occurs when the port is incorrect.